# external javascript/jquery does not load inside of django project

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am working on a django project that works with a postgres database.

I have a search form that allows users to search the database.  The search form works just fine.  I wanted to make it a little more user-friendly by adding autocomplete functionality to the form using javascript & jquery.

If I include the jquery in my html document body, everything works fine.
Example `search.html` (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availStations = 
        ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'pink', 'black'];

    $(".stations").autocomplete({
        source: availStations
    });
});
</script>
<br>
<form action = "/search/" method = "get">
<div class = "ui-widget">
<label for="stations">Search for: </label>
    <input type = "text" name ="q" class="stations">

[....]
```

I want to move this to an external file (`item_search.js`) and include `<script src="item_search.js"></script>` in my html body.

`item_search.js` looks like this:

```
  $(function() {
    var availStations = 
        ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'pink', 'black'];

    $(".stations").autocomplete({
        source: availStations
    });
});
```

When I do so and open the `search.html` file directly everything works fine.  But if I open it by running `python manage.py runserver` the jquery autocomplete does not work  My console shows the following message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-form/item_search.js
```

Obviously when I open `search.html` directly it's not connecting at all with the django project so the search doesn't actually work but at least the autocomplete does.  What could be going on??

Comment: Exactly what the error message says, that file doesn't exist at that location.

Comment: You need to prepend static url and put this js file in that directory

Comment: I think you forgot run [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)

Comment: Yes, I actually didn't know about static files. TY karthik & lalo.   Following the django docs here made everthing work:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: No, Ohgodwhy, the file DOES exist... that's why it works outside of django.  I just needed to set up the static files so it works inside my django project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup staticfiles if you want to use the built in django server.
Then into your template you can refer to the static location as

```
{% load static from staticfiles  %}
<html>
...
<script src="{% static "item_search.js" %}"></script>
```

This assumes that you have the item_search.js into the STATIC_ROOT.
Also don't forget to run collectstatic after each modification of the file.